# How to add new column based on the condition of another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a dataframe that consists some variables such as country, revenue, cost, and I have a constant value.

I want to create new column based on some range I defined and I tried this:

```
my_df['flag'] = my_df.apply(lambda row: row.cost - constant < row.revenue < row.cost + constant, 1,0)
```

It gave me a result but the flag column is full of 'False' value. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
my_df['flag'] = np.where(my_df.revenue.between(my_df.cost - constant, 
                                               my_df.cost + constant,
                                               inclusive='neither'), 1, 0)
```

Or:

```
my_df['flag'] = my_df.revenue.between(my_df.cost - constant, 
                                      my_df.cost + constant,
                                      inclusive='neither').astype(int)
```